# Passing GET variable to php EXEC

Tags: php, variables, exec

I've tried searching but haven't had much luck- apologies if this is answered somewhere.

I'm playing with a few bits and pieces and I was trying to pass a URL variable to EXEC.
Here's what I was trying..
sc.exe is a program I have to pass a URL- the $GET_ID variable has to come from the URL

```
  $GET_ID =$_GET= ['myid'];
  exec('sc.exe --url=http://localhost/DS1/test.php?ID='.$GET_ID.'&TEST=1');
  echo $GET_ID;
```

When I try this code out- the GET variable doesn't seem to be passed, the program gets 
http://localhost/DS1/test.php?ID=&TEST=1'

I've done a bit of searching.. and this seems to be a restriction of sorts.. So what is the solution/ workaround ?

thanks

Comment: Stupid question ... but have you included the 'myid' in the query string with an actual value?  Because it should work as you have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra `=` in your code. This should work:

```
$GET_ID = $_GET['myid'];
```

however, directly passing user data to the command line is **highly dangerous!** It allows an attacker to execute arbitrary commands on the command line.

You *must* use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
$GET_ID = escapeshellarg($_GET['myid']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `=` after $_GET.